# Clang failed with exit code 1 error in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, clang, xcode4.5

what is this error.. I'm trying to converting a non-ARC project to arc project and error is showing 
 `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1`

```
ProcessPCH /Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Corlocation-Prefix-fjwexhbcqsylinfenhkyculomcng/Corlocation-Prefix.pch.pth Corlocation/Corlocation-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/amit/Desktop/My Apps/Corlocation"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -iquote /Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/Corlocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Corlocation.build/Corlocation-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/Corlocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Corlocation.build/Corlocation-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/Corlocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Corlocation.build/Corlocation-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/Corlocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Corlocation.build/Corlocation-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/Corlocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Corlocation.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/Corlocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Corlocation.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator fno-objc-arc --serialize-diagnostics /Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Corlocation-Prefix-fjwexhbcqsylinfenhkyculomcng/Corlocation-Prefix.pch.dia -c "/Users/amit/Desktop/My Apps/Corlocation/Corlocation/Corlocation-Prefix.pch" -o /Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Corlocation-Prefix-fjwexhbcqsylinfenhkyculomcng/Corlocation-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Corlocation-gfdftvxjfdzkejebtysirafavnmv/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Corlocation-Prefix-fjwexhbcqsylinfenhkyculomcng/Corlocation-Prefix.pch.d

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'fno-objc-arc'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are use the **fno-objc-arc** that's a command line argument, you probably need to prefix it with a hyphen, such as with:

Replace **fno-objc-arc to -fno-objc-arc**

Answer (score 1):

`fno-objc-arc` should be `-fno-objc-arc` and is used to turn off ARC for the file, so there is obviously a mistake in your Xcode project settings.

See the screenshot in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) for details of where this is set.